# Mule - test an http get request with choice component

Tags: http, expression, mule, mule-studio

I have the following flow :

```
 <flow name="SOAPWebService" doc:name="SOAPWebService">

<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8088/esb/"   exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">          
</http:inbound-endpoint>

    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload.contains('c22')]">
            <set-variable variableName="paramCtr" value="#[message.inboundProperties['ctr']]" doc:name="conteneur"/>
            <set-variable variableName="paramC" value="#[message.inboundProperties['c']]" doc:name="critere"/>
            <component class="com.example.components.SampleComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
            <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\resources\PrepareRequestXMLPort.xsl" doc:name="XSLT">
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramCtr" value="#[flowVars['paramCtr']]"/>
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramC" value="#[flowVars['paramC']]"/>
            </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/ClientsDB/port" doc:name="PortWS"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-variable variableName="paramCtr" value="#[message.inboundProperties['ctr']]" doc:name="conteneur"/>
            <set-variable variableName="paramC" value="#[message.inboundProperties['c']]" doc:name="critere"/>
            <component class="com.example.components.SampleComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
            <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\resources\PrepareRequestXMLDouane.xsl" doc:name="XSLT">
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramCtr" value="#[flowVars['paramCtr']]"/>
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramC" value="#[flowVars['paramC']]"/>
            </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/ClientsDB/douane" doc:name="DouaneWS"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>


<byte-array-to-string-transformer   doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\output" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml " responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Outgoing File"/>
```

I want to test if an http request like `http://localhost:8088/esb/?type=xxxx&id=1234` if it contains the String `xxxx` in a way to route the request to the desired web service proxy.
I've tried withe the expression `expression="#[string.contains['xxxxx']]"` but it does not seem to work.

any idea?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your http inbound use set-variable to store your query params into flow variables.
And then use the flow variales in your expression.

```
<set-variable value="#[message.inboundProperties['id']]" variableName="paramId"></set-variable>
<set-variable value="#[message.inboundProperties['type']]" variableName="paramType"></set-variable>


or you can directly use inbound property for comparision.

    <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['type']== 'XXXX']">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didnt get your first solution.
the second one gives as an output 
org.mule.module.cxf.support.StreamClosingInterceptor$1@ecc6dc

Comment: the exception is not related to this choice router. Did you try loggers and see where exactly in the flow this exception is thrown. Can you provide the full flow.

Comment: I dont know exactly what happens into the choice component , but what I only got when I run the flow is org.mule.module.cxf.support.StreamClosingInterceptor$1@ecc6dc
instead of a soap response.
when I dont use the choce component I get the soap response normally, but when I add the choice and another web service proxyI got the above responce.

Comment: So your original post related to choice is solved right. So upvote ans accept this answer. Coming to your new issue I guess it resembles the issue you posted earlier  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545096/mule-esb-choice-flow-control-route/16546545#16546545

Comment: I've created another post for the new issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613148/mule-choice-component-issue
really appreciate your help.

Comment: As explained earlier you need to explicitly provide a transformer to convert the response you get from any of the calls made inside your choice router. see the response for the post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545096/mule-esb-choice-flow-control-route/16546545#16546545

Comment: I didnt get it in this case, shall I replace the byte Array to String by an Object to xml component ??
thank you.

Comment: Yes. You need to provide a transformer which can understand your response objects.

Comment: Can you help creating that transformer ?? Cause when I put an object to xml component it doesnt work . Thank you

Comment: try adding byte array to string transformers inside your when and otehrwise sections after your http:outbound.

Comment: I have updated the flow in your latest question. Try that. Hope it works.

Comment: Ok, i've updated the question, now I have another output, could you please check it in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613148/mule-choice-component-issue
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two things: You will need to replace "string" with the property you want to execute on. Either a message property or payload etc. i.e #[payload.contains...].

"contains" is a Java method on java.lang.String so you need to use standard Java method invocation with () instead of [].

Working example:

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[payload.contains('xxxx')]">

        <logger level="ERROR" message="YES" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <logger level="ERROR" message="NO" />
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Or directly work off inbound properties for your query params: